# ExpectedException in jUnit?

Tags: junit, nunit, assertions, expected-exception

Is there an equivalent to NUnit's ExpectedException or Assert.Throws<> in jUnit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

junit4:

```
@Test(expected = org.dom4j.DocumentException.class)
void shouldThrowException() {
    getFile(null);
}
```

junit3:

```
void testShouldThrowException() {
    try {
      getFile(null);
      fail("Expected Exception DocumentException");
    } catch(DocumentException e) {}
}
```

Comment: I have updated this answer to include a way to do this in jUnit3

Comment: The good thing about the "JUnit3" approach is that you can then write one exception-test-case per line, whereas you need five lines for each with the "JUnit4" approach. See my answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15385613/974531

Comment: Actually the answer using `ExpectedException` by @Maciej is better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4265441/53444

Answer (score 12):

You might also consider taking a look at the ExpectedException class which provides richer exception matching.

https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Exception-testing

Not only you can match the exception class but also you can apply custom matchers to its message.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Groovy for your junit tests you can use [shouldFail](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/GroovyTestCase.html#shouldFail%28groovy.lang.Closure%29).

Here is an example using junit3 style:

```
void testShouldThrowException() {
    def message = shouldFail(DocumentException) {
        documentService.getFile(null)
    }
    assert message == 'Document could not be saved because it ate the homework.'
}
```